# package installtion issue , rpm spec file , which include yum to install dependence

Tags: fedora, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

im having this part of spec file ,

```
%post
%{__mv} %{_sysconfdir}/sysconfig/data.py /opt/data.py
%{__mv} %{_sysconfdir}/sysconfig/get-pip.py /opt/get-pip.py



yum -y install python-psycopg2
python /opt/get-pip.py
pip install setuptools --no-use-wheel --upgrade
pip install requests


echo -e "*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/python  /opt/data.py"  >> /var/spool/cron/root

%files
%{_sysconfdir}/sysconfig/data.py
%{_sysconfdir}/sysconfig/get-pip.py

%changelog
```

the rpmbuild without error , but when i try to install the package its stuck , 
i've doubt about dependence installation , im using yum am i right or there is different way to to yum here

Comment: FYI, the preferred way to add yourself to `cron` is to drop a file in `/etc/cron.d` and then it would also be removed when uninstalled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it stuck because you are trying to run multiple YUM/RPM processes (Your package and python-psycopg2).
However, you should not run yum or rpm within you rpm, but declare python-psycopg2 as a dependency, so YUM will install it **before** installing your RPM.

Answer (score -3):

Just put the package in Requires in your rpm spec
ex:-

Requires: python-psycopg2

Comment: You came back nearly three years later to repeat the previous answer?