# yum/rpm install command in post install script of rpm spec file

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, yum, deb

I would like to create .rpm file with optional dependencies. ie if "dependency" is not installed because of missing file/network issues, the entire rpm install should not halt. 
 Whereas in "Weakdependency" section of http://www.rpm.org/wiki/PackagerDocs/Dependencies states that it is not supported by RPM specification. So i want to do turnaround approach by putting optional dependency packages in "post" install script. When i am including "yum install " in the postscript, at the time of execution it is going into waiting state (with no messages), when i killed process it giving messages like this..

```
Non-fatal POSTIN scriptlet failure in rpm package
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
  The other application is: yum
    Memory :  71 M RSS (365 MB VSZ)
    Started: Wed Mar 18 13:17:45 2015 - 00:16 ago
    State  : Sleeping, pid: 3870
```

Required packages are getting installed properly with this error in optional dependencies.
I think it is going to deadlock situation as both `yum` processes are waiting for completion of others. 
Is there  any better way to fix this type of optional dependency issue in RPM standard?

Comment: You should include your current SPEC file or at least the %post section.

Comment: Here my rpm is dependent on Python where as i want it to weak dependent on python-pip. 
`Requires: python 
%post
yum install python-pip`

Comment: I believe you are running into this problem:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989908/package-installtion-issue-rpm-spec-file-which-include-yum-to-install-depende   -- Not sure how to get around it though.  will look at it again.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a shell script that does what you need and leave 'yum' out of your spec file because of this problem ([package installtion issue , rpm spec file , which include yum to install dependence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989908/package-installtion-issue-rpm-spec-file-which-include-yum-to-install-depende)).

In the shell script (similar to any install.sh script), have it check on optional dependencies and install them if needed along with the RPM described in your post.

Comment: how will we invoke such a script? @GoinOff

Comment: Invoke it in the `%pre` section of the spec file.  I have done similar where the `%pre` section installs  needed dependencies automatically before the rpm installs.

Comment: But over there as well we many not be able to ```yum install``` in the script, right?

Comment: Well, you could wrap the install of the rpm in a shell script where `yum install` would work before installing the rpm.